# LCM calculation bug in GCD/LCM x86 Intel NASM assembly program

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

I created a similar program in C++ first, and then I decided to try to write it in x86 assembly language (the type of assembly I was taught in college).  I've already completed the C++ version, and my assembly version is almost complete.

I did some desk-checking on both versions, first using (2400, 3750).  I got the same LCM results in both versions, which is good.  However, when I used larger numbers (19000, 8200), my assembly program crashed while my C++ version displayed the correct results.  I suspect it has to do with my assembly variable sizes and/or my register use for division when calculating the LCM.

I tested my LCM calculations (minus the division operation) by outputting the dividend (first number times second number) and the divisor (GCD result).  I get the correct test results, so I think there is something wrong with my register use.  I have already tested my GCD calculations prior to this, so that shouldn't be part of the problem.

```
%include "macros.s"

.DATA

num_lbl:   DB   "> Numbers (2): ", 0
gcd_lbl:   DB   "*** GCD: ", 0
lcm_lbl:   DB   "*** LCM: ", 0

num1:   DD   0
num2:   DD   0

num1_cpy:   DD   0
num2_cpy:   DD   0

gcd:   DD   0
lcm:   DD   0

.CODE
.STARTUP

xor       EAX, EAX
xor       EBX, EBX
xor       ECX, ECX
xor       EDX, EDX
xor       EDI, EDI
xor       ESI, ESI

main:
     nwln
     nwln
     PutStr   num_lbl
     nwln
     nwln
     GetLInt   [num1]
     GetLInt   [num2]

     mov   EAX, [num1]
     mov   [num1_cpy], EAX
     mov   EBX, [num2]
     mov   [num2_cpy], EBX

     call   calc_euclidean
     call   calc_lcm

     nwln
     PutStr   gcd_lbl
     PutLInt   [gcd]
     nwln
     PutStr   lcm_lbl
     PutLInt   [lcm]
     nwln

     .EXIT

calc_euclidean:
               mov   EAX, [num2]
               cmp   EAX, 0
               jne   chk_swap

               mov   EAX, [num1]
               mov   [gcd], EAX

               ret

calc_lcm:
         mov   EAX, [num1_cpy]
         mov   EDX, [num2_cpy]
         mul   EDX

         mov   EDI, EAX

         xor   EBX, EBX

         mov   EDX, EDI
         shr   EDX, 16
         mov   EAX, EDI
         mov   BX, [gcd]
         div   BX

         mov   SI, AX
         mov   [lcm], SI

         ret         

chk_swap:
         mov   EAX, [num1]
         mov   EBX, [num2]
         cmp   EAX, EBX
         jl    swap

after_check:
            jmp   loop

swap:
     mov   EAX, [num1]
     mov   EBX, [num2]

     ; temp
     mov   ECX, [num2]

     ; num2 = num1
     ; num1 = temp
     mov   EBX, EAX
     mov   EAX, ECX

     mov   [num1], EAX
     mov   [num2], EBX

     jmp   after_check

loop:
     mov   EDX, [num1]
     shr   EDX, 16
     mov   EAX, [num1]
     mov   BX, [num2]
     div   BX

     mov   EDI, [num1]
     mov   ESI, [num2]
     mov   EDI, ESI
     mov   [num1], EDI
     mov   [num2], EDX

     jmp   calc_euclidean
```

Comment: Have you single-stepped the code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes I have.  The problem is in the LCM calculations, and I do get the correct dividend and divisor for all test cases.  It appears that something is going wrong with the division when using larger numbers  I still believe that there is something wrong with my variable initialization and register use.

Comment: I rolled it back to the last edit, because it does not make sense to fix bugs of a the question based on the answers received. The question becomes senseless for future readers if the essential content (the bug in question) is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `calc_lcm` procedure:

```
         mov   BX, [gcd]
         div   BX

         mov   SI, AX
         mov   [lcm], SI
```

When `num1` is 19200 and `num2` is 8200, `gcd` becomes 200. And here you attempt to compute lcm(19200, 8200) by dividing the product of `num1` and `num2` (19200 * 8200 = 157440000) by `gcd` (200):

```
157440000 / 200 = 787200
```

**Edit:** fixed typo.

787200 does not fit in 16 bits. You need to convert your code to use 32-bit `div` instead of 16-bit `div` to handle bigger numbers than now.

So it would be:

**Edit**: Added code.

```
xor    ebx,ebx   ; this you have already.
mov    bx,[gcd]
xor    edx,edx   ; zero edx, as edx:eax gets divided by ebx...
div    ebx       ; ...now.

mov    [lcm],eax ; store the lcm into memory
```

Comment: I have tried div with a 32-bit register, but the program is still crashing.  Either I have to make changes elsewhere as well, or I cannot work with such numbers in 32-bit mode (thus I cannot use 64-bit registers).

Comment: Okay, gotcha.  Even with the 32-bit division, I'm still experiencing crashing.  Is the problem somewhere else, or am I unable to divide a 32-bit number by another 32-bit number?

Comment: You need to zero `edx`, as `edx:eax` gets divided by the divisor in 32-bit division like `div ebx`.

Comment: It works now.  Thanks!  Could you please tell me how this worked?  I was taught (for 32-bit division) to put the high-order bits into EDX, the lower ones into EAX, then divide by a different 16-bit register.

Comment: Oh well, using `bl`/`bx`/`ebx`/`rbx` as divisor: `div bl ; ax/bl`. `div bx ; dx:ax/bx`. `div ebx ; edx:eax/ebx`. `div rbx ; rdx:rax/rbx`. I'd say `div reg16` is rather 16-bit division or 32/16 division, not 32-bit division, as the divisor, quotient and remainder are all 16-bit values. Only the dividend can be 32-bit value in `div reg16`.

Comment: I see.  After tinkering with my code again, I was able to get the same LCM (and no crashing) by ONLY moving EDI into EAX, moving [gcd] into EBX, and dividing by EBX.  Essentially, I was doing EAX/EBX.  I suppose this is also a valid form of division.